# How do I properly access inherited methods and constructors in c++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I have a Sphere class which inherits a Point object for the center. When I create a Sphere object through the Sphere constructor, it always initializes the center to 0,0,0, but it will correctly set the radius.

Accessing the Sphere's setCenter() method also has no impact. The only way I can effectively change the X, Y, Z co-ordinates of the Sphere's center Point is to call the Point's setX() etc. methods.

I apologize if this is a blatantly obvious answer, but I'm new to C++ and struggling with the transition. If I've left out any important information, please don't hesitate to let me know. Here is the relevant code:

## MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "MovingSphere.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream inFile("sphere.txt");
    int X, Y, Z, R, DX, DY, DZ;
    if (inFile) {

        inFile >> X >> Y >> Z >> R
            >> DX >> DY >> DZ;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "\neRR: Cannot find input file.\n\n";
    }

    // create a sphere
    Sphere sphereInstance(X, Y, Z, R);
    sphereInstance.setCenter(1, 2, 3);
    sphereInstance.setX(3);

    cout << endl <<
        "X = " << sphereInstance.getX() << endl <<
        "Y = " << sphereInstance.getY() << endl <<
        "Z = " << sphereInstance.getZ() << endl;

return 0;

}
```

## Point.cpp

```
#include "Point.h"

Point::Point() : x(0), y(0), z(0) {   // default constructor (point at 0,0,0)
}

Point::Point(int X, int Y) : x(), y(), z(0) {      // constructor for 2d point
}

Point::Point(int X, int Y, int Z) : x(), y(), z() { // constructor for 3d point
}

// set the points X coordinate (mutator)
void Point::setX(int newX) {
    x = newX;
}
... etc.
```

## Point.h

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H

class Point {

public:
    Point ();                         // default constructor (0,0,0);
    Point(int X, int Y);              // constructor for 2d point
    Point(int X, int Y, int Z);       // constructor for 3d point

    void setX(int newX);              // declaration

    int getX() const;                 // declaration
etc...


private:

    int x, y, z;  // coordinates of point

};

#endif  /* POINT_H */
```

## Sphere.cpp

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <math.h>
#include "Sphere.h"

Sphere::Sphere() : 
    center(), radius(0) {// default constructor (a point at 0,0,0)
}

Sphere::Sphere(int X, int Y, int Z, int R) {     // sphere constructor
    center = Point(X, Y, Z);
    radius = R;
}

// set the sphere's center (mutator)
void Sphere::setCenter(int X, int Y, int Z) {
    center.setX(X);
    center.setY(Y);
    center.setZ(Z);
}
... etc.
```

## Sphere.h

```
#ifndef SPHERE_H
#define SPHERE_H

#include "Point.h"

class Sphere: public Point {

public:
    Sphere();          // default constructor (a point at 0,0,0)
    Sphere (int X, int Y, int Z, int R); // sphere constructor

    void setRadius(int newRadius); // declaration
    void setCenter(int X, int Y, int Z); // declaration

    int getRadius() const;         // declaration

private:
    Point center;      // center of sphere
    int radius;        // radius of sphere

};

#endif  /* SPHERE_H */
```

## The Output

```
X = 3
Y = 0
Z = 0
```

Comment: Can you show `Sphere::getX` and the `Sphere` header?

Comment: Please include the definitions of `Sphere` and `Point` classes as well (i.e. the headers). Also, `Sphere` should most likely not inherit from `Point`. Inheritance expresses **is-a** relationships. Under most normal definitions, "a sphere *is a* point" is **not** true.

Comment: Your sphere has two centers! One is the 'center' member variable. The other is the point that it is derived from! (Since you have said, through inheritance, that a sphere is a point.) You are setting one and then testing the other. (You are expecting `Sphere::getX` to somehow magically call `center.getX()` rather than `Point::getX`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz This seems like exactly my problem. Can you be more specific? 

Edit: You edited before I posted. Processing that now.

Comment: Sphere does not have the "isa" replationship to Point. The centre along with the radius should be member variables.

Comment: @Justin: You misunderstand inheritance. It represents an "is a" relationship. Since you inherited Sphere from Point, then a Sphere *is* a Point. Since a Point has an X, Y, and Z coordinate, and a Sphere *is* a Point, so does a Sphere. But then you went and added a `center` to a Sphere -- so a Sphere is a Point that also has a center. So now it has two X, two Y, and two Z coordinates. The one it already had by virtue of being a Point, and the one for the center you added to it. You are setting the center's X, Y, and Z coordinates but then testing the Sphere's X, Y, and Z coordinates.

Comment: Is `Sphere` derived from `Point`? If so you should state it clearly in the question. I would probably not use that inheritance relation though.

Comment: @Angew: In some cases, it might be sensible to think of a Sphere as a point that also has some additional properties such as a radius. The problem is that the rest of his code doesn't treat a Sphere that way. (But you're 100% right to point out that most likely, inheritance is the wrong tool for this job.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: speaking as a mathematician by training, if something has a radius then it can't be a point, so in addition a different name would be needed for the base class :-) But really I agree with you, I can imagine something that *serves* as a point but also has arbitrary meta-data attached to it, including maybe a piece of metadata called its "radius". I'm just scared of the notion that, geometrically speaking, someone might think of a sphere as being a "really big point".

Comment: @SteveJessop: A "really big thing that acts like point in that it has an X, Y, and Z coordinate" might be a sensible model for a Sphere. But it most likely isn't. It's hard to come up with a name for a "thing with a center" that could include a point or a sphere.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: yes, or a sphere might *really* represent a point, but one resulting from a physical measurement with the centre being its best-estimate location and the radius indicating the 95% confidence. But for your "thing-with-a-centre": maybe `PositionedSolid` or something. For "having co-ordinates" maybe `Position` or `Location`. I'd still be a little more comfortable if a sphere had a location rather than being one, but at least a sphere doesn't contradict any of the fundamental properties of a location ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Sphere: public Point {
```

This says a Sphere *is* a Point and starts with everything a Point has, including an X, Y, and Z coordinate.

```
private:
   Point center;      // center of sphere
```

This says a Sphere *has* a Point, called `center`. This Point that a Sphere has also has an X, Y, and Z coordinate, as all Points do.

So a Sphere both is a Point and has a Point, each with an X, Y, and Z coordinate. This can't be what you wanted, and your code fails when it sets one of these two Points and then gets the other.. Pick one model and stick to it.

If you need to treat a Sphere like a Point polymorphically, then remove `center`-- in this model, a Sphere is a Point that also has a radius. If you don't need to treat a Sphere like a Point, then don't inherit from Point -- in this model, a Sphere is not a point but has a Point and a radius.

Comment: Thank you. This brings up another question though. Should I create a new question or ask it here?

Comment: Since you already asked it here, I'll answer it here. You should ask it here, since that's what you already did, and since I'm answering it here now anyway.

Comment: What is the best way to access the member variables for my center Point? In Java it would have been something like sphereInstance.center.getX() but I can't find a c++ equivalent.

Comment: You made `center` private, so it can only be accessed by class member functions. You could add functions to access the `center` member, that do `center.getX()` inside the member function. You could also add a function `getCenter` the returns a reference to the center member. You could make `center` public.

Comment: Thank you. I went with some getCenterX() {center.getX()} type methods.

Answer (score 2):

Your `Point` 2 and 3 parameter constructors do nothing with the inputs. Change them to

```
Point::Point(int X, int Y) : x(X), y(Y), z(0) { }

Point::Point(int X, int Y, int Z) : x(X), y(X), z(Z) { }
```

If `center` is a `Point` data member of `Sphere`, then you should prefer initialization in the constructor initialization list rather than assignment in the body of the constructor:

```
Sphere::Sphere(int X, int Y, int Z, int R) : center(X,Y,Z), radius(R) { }
```

I edited a colon into the statement, but need at least 6 characters.

Comment: and the same for the 2 parameter version of the `Point` constructor.

Comment: This wasn't the entire problem, but it still helped me to understand constructors better, thank you.

Comment: @Justin I can see from comments to your question that you had an issue with inheritance. That wasn't clear in the question itself, but you should really ask yourself if you want a `Sphere` to be a `Point`. When I've done 3D geomerty stuff before, we tended to separate shapes from positions (but we had other constraints that may be different to yours). In any case, you want either inheritance or containment (data member), but not both.

Answer (score 1):

You don't show how `Point` and `Sphere` are related, but I guess that `Sphere` inherits from `Point`...

```
class Point
{
    ...
};

class Sphere : public Point
{
    ...
};
```

If you want to call e.g. the base constructor you do it in the initializer list:

```
Sphere::Sphere(int X, int Y, int Z, int R)
    : Point(X, Y, Z), radius(R)
{
}
```

As for other functions, if they are in the base class you can use them as if they were member of the child class:

```
void Sphere::setCenter(int X, int Y, int Z)
{
    setX(X);
    setY(Y);
    setZ(Z);
}
```

Since `Sphere` also is a `Point` (due to the inheritance) you don't need the `center` member variable.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should clarify exactly how Sphere is related to Point first (either Sphere has-a Point i.e. member, or Sphere is-a Point i.e. inheritance).

Your exact problem however is this:

- Sphere's setCenter() method updates Sphere::center
- Sphere uses Point's getX/Y/Z(), and these use the x/y/z in Point

That is, setCenter() updates things that have nothing to do with getX/Y/Z().